# Randomly load wallpaper via css and html

Tags: php, html, css, image, random

I'm a newbie on css and html and even coding. I'm currently making my own start page with a local path, which loads my bookmark on an html file. The background-image control passes through the `style.css` file. I've googled some solutions as to creating a php script to load random pictures over css and html, and I've tried various solutions, however it doesn't seem to work for me. So here we go:

the index.html file for passing the background-image:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

and the style.css:

```
body {
background-image: url("Wallpaper01.jpg") ;
```

}

I don't know how to change it since I downloaded the code. Also the .jpg file is in the same directory as the html and css.

Can someone please help me out to have a random image with this?
Please provide the code to do it, place to insert it, or whatever I need to, that will help a lot more than just telling me what to do.

Many, many thanks if someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
<?php
  $bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

**CSS (in the head)**

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <style type="text/css">
                <!--
                body{
                background: url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
                }
                -->
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
             <!-- website -->
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Edit (user's comments)**

```
<?php
          $bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' ); // array of filenames

          $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
          $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>

        <html lang="en"> 
            <head> 
                <meta charset=utf-8> 
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /> 
                <title>Start Page</title> 
                <style type="text/css">
                        <!--
                        body{
                        background: url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
                        }
                        -->
                </style>
            </head>
            <body> 
                <div id="one">01 <div class="title">General</div> 
                <div class="links"> <a href="google.com">Google </a> 

                </div> 
            </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, so where do I put the first part of code in?

Comment: Above the doctype `<html><head>z

Comment: Um...so this part goes where?


<?php
  $bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>

and my css file does not contain <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <style type="text/css">

Comment: Again: Above the doctype `<html><head>`

Comment: sorry, is it inside my index.html?

Comment: Change index.html to index.php

Comment: i just changed it into index.php, so it look like this as it did,
where do I insert it?
//////////////
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Start Page</title>
<body>
  <div id="one">01
   <div class="title">General</div>
   <div class="links">
   <a href="http://www.google.com">Google </a> 
                </div>
  </div>

Comment: User, this code is using a nifty language called PHP. You'll learn that some of the neat things you can't do with HTML and CSS can easily be accomplished with a bit of PHP. PHP is different because it's a server-side script, which means it runs on your server (probably Apache). HTML, CSS, and JavaScript are client side scripts, which means they are run by your browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.). I recommend you look into serverside scripting; there are some pretty powerful techniques you can use to make a website with them.

Comment: Place the `PHP` just above `PHP HERE <html lang="en">`

Comment: Under my index.php(which is all the same except it changed into .php), I just copied the edited code however it goes green only for the php part. it's on Coda software under Mac

Comment: No, you need to place the code above de `Doctype` because `programming languages` are reading from up -> down. Just changed the filename to `index.php` or create an other new file? I don't get the problem right now, sorry.

Comment: em.. I save the index.html as index.php and put all the edited code into, and I don't know what is a doctype

Comment: Please copy the whole code in my edit under `Edit (user's comments)` and paste in in your PHP file. I also recommend you to read some tutorials http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Comment: Change the syntax to PHP or reopen code, this code will work just test it.

Comment: OK it seems to work now, however in style.css[[
body {
 background-image: url("Wallpaper55.jpg") ;
 color: #000;
} ]] do i need to delete the background-image code?

Comment: Did you insert the links to the background, i don't think so.

Comment: `$bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' );` place your background. Please follow some HTML en PHP tutorials, this is basic stuff.

Comment: `background: url(img/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>` you need to change it to `background: url(<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>` now it's checks in the map `img` but you don't have one.

Comment: I did change it, do I need to change    background: url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat; into my directory?

Comment: I don't know where you are saving you're images.

Comment: images are under Startpage folder, same as index.php and style.css...so what do i do with it?

Comment: Don't get it anymore but you;re website is `http://www.website.com/Startpage/images/Wallpaper52.png`? just do : `background: url(http://www.website.com/Startpage/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;`

Comment: since it's my local file, i do it like this as I always did for local directory.                background: url(file:///Users/MyName/Documents/Startpage/index.html<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat; but still no work

Comment: `background: url(../<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;` - `background: url(../img/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;` - `background: url(../images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;` -

Comment: they're not in sub folders called img or images...so I pretty sure nothing do with that

Comment: background: url(file:///Users/MyName/Documents/Startpage/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;  no work :(

Comment: `background: url(<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;` and PLEASE again, Google for some tutorials i can help you anymore. Sorry.

Comment: I found the problem, I preview it in Coda and it works, but do not work in Chrome for the index.php

Comment: Check the debugger in Chrome and watch where 'Chrome' is searching for the image. I answered the main question so if it helped you please check this question as answered, thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nathan, you helped a lot to me. You're such a kind person.